# Zf2 view using json model

Tags: json, zend-framework2, jsonmodel

In zend framework 2, i have the configuration below in module.config.php:

```
'strategies' => array(
    'ViewJsonStrategy',
)
```

And my controller is:

```
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
$view = new JsonModel(array(
            'username' =>  ucfirst( $username ),
            'datarr' => array(

                'a' => 'A',
                'b' => 'B',
                'c' => 'C',
                'd' => 'D',

            ),
        ));
```

in my view just getting:

```
{ "username" : "Reynold", "datarr" : {"a":"A", "b":"B", "c":"C", "d":"D" } }
```

When I am using  `$view = new ViewModel();`, I am getting right, and while using the `JsonModel` I am getting the above one, can anyone help me to find out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with this. The JsonModel is used for ajax-requests, whereas the ViewModel is used for normal http-requests.

You can use the response from the JsonModel as a javascript-object.
Here is an example with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourUrl,
    success: function(d) {
        console.log(d.username);
        console.log(d.datarr.a);
    }
});
```

In your controller, you can check if it is an ajax-request like this:

```
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
   // return json-model
}
```